# Twitter json + php

Tags: php

I am pulling the twitter json feed and parsing it with php. 
One of the values in the array is `[created_at] => Wed Jun 22 06:19:31 +0000 2011` . 
However I only want the "`Wed Jun 22`".

I am currently using `$data->created_at = substr($data->created_at, 0, 10);`

but for example if a month/day has 4 characters it will mess it up so I need a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/([a-zA-Z]+ [a-zA-Z]+ [0-9]+)/", "Wed Jun 22 06:19:31 +0000 2011", $date);
$date = $date[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo date('D M d',strtotime($array['created_at']));
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/MCcZ5NXY)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use strtotime to create a new date with php date function.

$new_date = date('D M n', strtotime($data->created_at));

Answer (score 0):

You should look into PHP's DateTime class, especially [DateTime::createFromFormat()](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). Creating a date/time object way cleaner solution than using `substr()`.
Plus, you know, if you ever wanted to store year...